# R: Crear una columna a partir de la suma de otra columna, con condición

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

tengo una base de datos que se ve así:

```
Añomes         Calificación       Cuentas     Defaults

2016-01-01          A               100          0
2016-01-01          B               90           0
2016-01-01          C               939          1
2016-01-01          D               354          2
2016-02-01          A               50           1 
2016-02-01          B               170          1
2016-02-01          C               380          3
2016-02-01          D               398          6 
2016-03-01          A               600          0
2016-03-01          B               678          3
2016-03-01          C               765          4
2016-03-01          D               998          6
2016-04-01          A               120          2
2016-04-01          B               250          5
```

Quiero agregarle una columna tal que, esta sea la suma total de las cuentas pero únicamente del mismo mes, es decir, que quede así:

```
Añomes         Calificación       Cuentas     Defaults      SUMA(Cuentas)

2016-01-01          A               100          0              1,483
2016-01-01          B               90           0              1,483
2016-01-01          C               939          1              1,483
2016-01-01          D               354          2              1,483
2016-02-01          A               50           1               998
2016-02-01          B               170          1               998
2016-02-01          C               380          3               998
2016-02-01          D               398          6               998
2016-03-01          A               600          0              3,041
2016-03-01          B               678          3              3,041
2016-03-01          C               765          4              3,041
2016-03-01          D               998          6              3,041
2016-04-01          A               120          2               370
2016-04-01          B               250          5               370
```

Intenté el siguiente código:

```
DF$Suma(Cuentas) <- sum(DF$Suma(Cuentas)[which(DF$Añomes == DF$Añomes)])
```

Sin embargo esto me arrojó una columna con la suma de todos los números en la columna cuentas de tal manera que todas las observaciones de esa nueva columna me dan el valor: 5.892.

¿Alguien podría sugerirme otra forma de lograrlo? Espero haber sido clara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola esto lo puedes realizar con dyplyr, como se muestra a continuación

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- structure(list(Añomes = structure(c(16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16832, 16832, 16832, 16832, 16861, 16861, 16861, 16861, 16892, 16892), class = "Date"),
                     Calificación = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"),
                     Cuentas = c(100L, 90L, 939L, 354L, 50L, 170L, 380L, 398L, 600L, 678L, 765L, 998L, 120L, 250L), 
                     Defaults = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Primero agrupas por Añomes, creas la variable y desagrupas

```
DF %>%
  group_by(Añomes) %>%
  mutate(`SUMA(Cuentas)` = sum(Cuentas)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 14 x 5
   Añomes     Calificación Cuentas Defaults `SUMA(Cuentas)`
   <date>     <chr>          <int>    <int>           <int>
 1 2016-01-01 A                100        0            1483
 2 2016-01-01 B                 90        0            1483
 3 2016-01-01 C                939        1            1483
 4 2016-01-01 D                354        2            1483
 5 2016-02-01 A                 50        1             998
 6 2016-02-01 B                170        1             998
 7 2016-02-01 C                380        3             998
 8 2016-02-01 D                398        6             998
 9 2016-03-01 A                600        0            3041
10 2016-03-01 B                678        3            3041
11 2016-03-01 C                765        4            3041
12 2016-03-01 D                998        6            3041
13 2016-04-01 A                120        2             370
14 2016-04-01 B                250        5             370
```

Comment: Funcionó, gracias! Tienes alguna sugerencia de cómo podría hacer esto si tengo una base de datos de 600 obs? esta rta me sirvió para mi df que era pequeño, pero ahora tengo otro que tiene muchas más obs y me tardaría mucho poniendo en structure(list... cada una de ellas.

Comment: Solo tiene que leer la base de datos que tenga, por ejemplo en un excel o csv. El `structure(list...)` no es necesario. Y aplicar el `group_by(...`